# polygon mumbai testnet doesn't revert error reason, instead confirm transaction with status:false

Tags: solidity, web3js, polygon, typescript

i use web3js to request to the polygon mumbai testnet using quicknode. when i use ganache, i get error revert reson easily but when i use mumbai testnet, it consume gas and return receipt with status false which means the transaction not successful but doesnt revert error.

this is my transaction:

> {"blockHash":"0xba6cc3f421fd1678a738227954c68e566f7db8e20813db13d8359416242de25a","blockNumber":35295713,"contractAddress":null,"cumulativeGasUsed":599199,"effectiveGasPrice":2500000016,"from":"0xd259dca1dad40c3bd798e308cf6c82db43d8d1dc","gasUsed":28854,"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000001000000000100000000000000000008100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000100000","status":false,"to":"0x35dee935f98e6996a307ae6240bd5a8a90c8e649","transactionHash":"0x598d91eb642cd010cee4a75d9aa72d714f2b5aa4f0f4348656baef84ea27cb66","transactionIndex":5,"type":"0x2","events":{"0":{"address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010","blockNumber":35295713,"transactionHash":"0x598d91eb642cd010cee4a75d9aa72d714f2b5aa4f0f4348656baef84ea27cb66","transactionIndex":5,"blockHash":"0xba6cc3f421fd1678a738227954c68e566f7db8e20813db13d8359416242de25a","logIndex":17,"removed":false,"id":"log_7ba9730e","returnValues":{},"signature":null,"raw":{"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000419b3d0d0600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021e1cc2aed8f00200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000083005327b2a2d557a29000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021ddb2771cbea020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008300532bcc56a628029","topics":["0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010","0x000000000000000000000000d259dca1dad40c3bd798e308cf6c82db43d8d1dc","0x0000000000000000000000003a22c8bc68e98b0faf40f349dd2b2890fae01484"]}}}}

and this is web3js request:

> 

```
export function createVoteCall(web3:any, contract:any, abi:any, 
contractAddress:any, voteName:string, candidate:any, fromAccount:any){
   
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    contract.methods.createVote(voteName, candidate).send({from:fromAccount,gas: 3000000})
    
    
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber:number, receipt:any){
           
            resolve("successful transaction: " + JSON.stringify(receipt)) 
            
        }).on('error', function(error:any, receipt:any) {
           
           
            reject("Error: " + error.reason)
            
            
        })
})
}
```

the contract function in solidity:

> 

```
    function createVote(string memory voteName, string[] 
    memory candidateOption) public returns(string memory){

    require(bytes(voteName).length > 0, "you must set a name for your voting.");
    require(candidateOption.length > 0, "Candidate options cannot be empty.");
    require(candidateVote[voteName].length == 0,"the Vote already existed!");
    
    candidateVote[voteName] = candidateOption;

    require(candidateVote[voteName].length > 0, "something is wrong!");

    return "create vote successful!";
    
}
```

if you would help me, i will be very glad.

Comment: Can you please add the contract function you are calling?

Comment: yes, of course, I add it to the above

Comment: Try one thing in the js code, 
use call instead of send and let me know if that works

Comment: call works but call doesnt change the state of function in solidity. my problem is that i want to use send and send function doesnt revert any error reason

Comment: There is this issue that you follow up https://github.com/web3/web3.js/issues/4787